# Why is it not showing me the permissions or the group on django?

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ53m.png)

Why is it not showing me the permissions or the group on django?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It does show you those.. The pattern shown is: `{app} | {model} | {permission}`

Example: `admin | log entry | Can add log entry`

Means whether the current object **can add** (create) a new instance of the **log entry** model that resides in **admin** app.